# Rails double polymorphism dependent: destroy not destroyed properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this model, a `LeaveManagementRule`. A `Rule` has a `sender`, a `receiver`. A sender can either be a `Role` or a `User` (same for a receiver):

```
class LeaveManagementRule < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :sender, polymorphic: true # Sender can be a Role or a User
  belongs_to :receiver , polymorphic: true # receiver can be a Role or a User
  ...
end
```

Here is the `User` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :leave_management_rules, as: :sender, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :leave_management_rules, as: :receiver, dependent: :destroy
  ...
end
```

The `Role` model is the same as the User model. For the purposes of this question, I don't feel the need to detail it.

Here is an extract of the `leave_management_rules` table in db:

```
mysql> select * from leave_management_rules;
+----+-----------+-------------+--------+-------------+---------------+------------+
| id | sender_id | sender_type | action | receiver_id | receiver_type | project_id |
+----+-----------+-------------+--------+-------------+---------------+------------+
|  1 |        56 | User        |      1 |          19 | Role          |         33 |
|  2 |       146 | User        |      2 |          56 | User          |         33 |
+----+-----------+-------------+--------+-------------+---------------+------------+
```

We are going to focus on the `user_id: 56`, which appears in the two entries here (as a `sender` for entry 1, as a `receiver` for entry 2).

Now, I am trying to delete the User 56 in my Rails console:

```
irb(main):020:0> u = User.find(56)
irb(main):021:0> u.destroy
```

So, I would expect my `leave_management_rules` table to now be empty. But there is still one entry left:

```
mysql> select * from leave_management_rules;
+----+-----------+-------------+--------+-------------+---------------+------------+
| id | sender_id | sender_type | action | receiver_id | receiver_type | project_id |
+----+-----------+-------------+--------+-------------+---------------+------------+
|  1 |        56 | User        |      1 |          19 | Role          |         33 |
+----+-----------+-------------+--------+-------------+---------------+------------+
```

Is there something I am doing wrong in my code ?

I am running `Rails 4.2.4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find an answer to why the `dependent: :destroy` callback would not trigger properly.

Instead, I've written a custom `before_destroy` callback for the `User` and `Role` models:

```
before_destroy :destroy_leave_management_rules

def destroy_leave_management_rules
  as_sender = LeaveManagementRule.where(sender: self)
  as_receiver = LeaveManagementRule.where(receiver: self)
  as_sender.destroy_all
  as_receiver.destroy_all
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are not doing well the `double-polimymorphic` association. Try something like this:

```
class UserRulesRelation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :origin, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :leave_management_rules, polymorphic: true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_rules_relations, as: :origin, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :sent, through: :user_rules_relations, source: :leave_management_rules, source_type: "User"
  has_many :received, through: :user_rules_relations, source: :leave_management_rules, source_type: "LeaveManagementRule"
end

class LeaveManagementRule < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_rules_relations, as: :origin, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :sent, through: :user_rules_relations, source: :leave_management_rules, source_type: "User"
  has_many :received, through: :user_rules_relations, source: :leave_management_rules, source_type: "LeaveManagementRule"
end
```

Comment: Thank you for these details, unfortunately I don't think I will reactor my  whole code structure as  I have nearly finished its development and several model depends on it. It works perfectly fine, appart from the  dependent: destroy callback being only called once. I guess I will call a custom method on before_destroy to manually trigger the expected process...